# Esconder region en APEX usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, apex

Algun experto en `Javascript` o `APEX` que me pueda asesorar, tengo un `Static Content` que se necesita esconder basado en una condicion cuando se haga una busqueda en un `Textbox`.

Se trata de que:

- Se introduce una numeracion en el text box y se de `enter`.
  Si ese numero corre en `Sistema_1`,  en mi layout puedes ver un Static Content para agregar informacion a actualizar para ese número, y tambien habilita un boton de actualizar.
- De lo contrario ese numero no puede ser actualizado, por ende mi boton de Actualizar y la región de actualizar contenido (campos en verde) los mantengo escondidos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se inicia ese modulo, solo aparece el textbox de la parte izquierda superior, se hace la busqueda y se llenan los campos, basicamente lo que esta marcado en verde debe esconderse basado en mi busqueda. Si es tal muestrame los campos, si no escondelos. Alguna sugerencia de como empezarlo o por donde?

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que:

- El nombre del item de busqueda es: **P6_BUSCAR**
- El nombre del boton: **ACTUALIZAR**
- El titulo de la region de contenido estatico es: **LAYOUT**

Basicamente lo que tienes que hacer es crear una accion dinamica asociadada a tu elemento **P6_BUSCAR**:

1. Clic derecho en tu elemento P6_BUSCAR, clic en create dynamic action.
2. Name: MOSTRAR/OCULTAR
3. When:

   - Event: Change
   - Selection Type: Item(s)
   - Item(s): P6_BUSCAR
4. Client-Side Condition

   - Type: Item = Value
   - Item: P6_BUSCAR
   - Value: Sistema_1
5. Clic en la accion verdadera que se creo (llamada show)

   - Action: Show
   - Selection Type: Button
   - Button: ACTUALIZAR
   - Fire on Initialization: Yes
6. Clic derecho en true, clic en create TRUE action

   - Action: Show
   - Selection Type: Region
   - Region: LAYOUT
   - Fire on Initialization: Yes
7. Clic derecho en false, clic en create FALSE action

   - Action: Hide
   - Selection Type: Button
   - Button: Actualizar
   - Fire on Initialization: Yes
8. Clic derecho en false, clic en create FALSE action

   - Action: Hide
   - Selection Type: Region
   - Region: LAYOUT
   - Fire on Initialization: Yes

Comment: Gracias, en el punto 5 mencionas ver las opciones del elemento Show, en el `Selection type`, olvide mencionar que mi boton de actualizar no es un elemento pick and drop de `APEX` si no un elemento de `JavaScript`, en esta situacion me imagino que hay en el `Selection Type`, habria que seleccionar `JavaScript Expression` del boton, cierto?

Comment: Si tu boton tiene asociado un ID estatico... Selection type: jQuery Selector, jQuery Selector: #ID